# Qt MainWindow crashes upon button click

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I've used Qt's MainWindow class before, and I have never had any problems.
Right now, I have a button called `addLocation` that is supposed to create a `QInputDialog` and get a string from the user, and add it to a `QStringList` called `locationList`, which is a public field of my `uiactions.h` file, declared like this within the header:

```
class UiActions{

public:
QStringList locationList;

//function prototypes

};
```

I have a function in my `mainwindow.cpp` file to handle the event of my `addLocation` button being clicked, defined as such:

```
void MainWindow::on_addLocation_clicked()
{
    UiActions actions;
    actions.addLocation();
}
```

And my `addLocation` function is defined as follows in my `uiactions.cpp` file:

```
void UiActions::addLocation()
{
bool j; //Input Dialog Handler
QDebug debugTxt(QtDebugMsg);
locationList << QInputDialog::getText(NULL, "Add Location",
                                      "Location Name:", QLineEdit::Normal,
                                      NULL, &j);
}
```

Whenever I click the `addLocation` button, the program shows an input dialog, lets me type something, and then hangs for a few seconds and crashes after clicking "ok."

I added some lines under the input dialog to see if the problem was in the `QInputDialog`, like this:

```
if(j){
   debugTxt << "Input dialog success";
}
else{
    debugTxt << "Input failed.";
}
```

And it would print out "Input dialog success" to the debug console, telling me the problem is not in my use of the `QInputDialog`.

When it crashes, this is all the error information I get:

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
[insert path to EXE here] crashed
```

I believe this is all of the relevant information. What would be causing the program to crash?

**EDIT**: I ran with the debugger (should have done this first) and I'm getting a segmentation fault. I wonder what would be causing this, as I'm not doing any pointer trickery. I have a suspicion that it has something to do with the way I'm using `QStringList locationList`

The highlighted assembly is `0x64942cb6  <+0x0000>         cmpl   $0xbab1f00d,(%edx)`

**EDIT 2**: I made a modification to the click event for my addLocation button, which is in my `mainwindow.cpp` file.

```
void MainWindow::on_addLocation_clicked()
{
UiActions actions;
//actions.addLocation();
actions.locationList << "Test Location" << "Other Data";
}
```

I get the same error when I try to add something to a QStringList field in the uiactions.h file as well. I'm almost positive I'm trying to access the data in there incorrectly now. Here's the interesting thing though. I have another button which I use to save the data in `locationList` to a text file, defined like this in my `uiactions.cpp` file:

```
bool UiActions::saveLocationList()
{
ofstream file;
file.open ("Location List.txt");
for(int i = 0;i < locationList.size(); i++){
    file << locationList[i].toUtf8().data() << "\n";
}
file.close();
return true;

}
```

which works fine.

**EDIT 3**: I added a debug line: `debugTxt << "\n" << locationList[0];` to the `addLocation` click event to see if the data was actually getting put into `locationList`, and it is. I'm completely confused now, since it seems I actually am accessing locationList correctly.

Comment: Discovered it's a segmentation fault after debugging but I'm still not sure how to fix it, added this info to the question.

Comment: @hyde I don't get an error on that line though. No warning or compiler error. If I change the name of the variable that is stored in to some variable that I haven't declared, I get a compiler error. The only place i have a `locationList` declared is in the `uiactions.h` file as a public field. If it was manipulating a local variable, wouldn't I be getting a "not declared in scope" error?

Comment: The second NULL in the getText worries me a bit. [According to the API](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html#getText) that arg is expecting a const reference ("const QString & text = QString()"). I'm not sure it'll fix your problem, but try just passing QString()?

Comment: @Alex P That second `NULL` is just the text that fills the `QInputDialog` text box by default; I want it to be empty. I just tried to add a QString there and it didn't change anything, the program still crashes.

Comment: `UIActions actions;` line in `MainWindow::on_addLocation_clicked()` defines a local variable. If I read between the lines, it *shadows* a class member variable with same name? In any case, it will go out of scope when method returns. If you intend the values to not disappear immediately, use a class member variables, not local variables. But that is *probably* not related to your crash (though it *might* be depending on what you do in code you do not show).

Comment: @hyde I'm basically instansiating `UiActions` within the function, I have that `UiActions actions;` line in every function in `MainWindow.cpp` because that seems to have worked for me. So what you're saying is any data I put into `locationList` within `MainWindow::on_addLocation_clicked()` is going to be lost when I get out of scope? Should I declare `UiActions actions` as a global instead?

I can provide the entirety of my code if you'd like.

Comment: You should probably declare `UIActions actions` as a member variable of your `MainWindow` class. Not global variable, those are generally evil, in OOP and in Qt apps.

Comment: what if you replace the first NULL in getText with `this`?

Comment: ...and if you're unclear on what is a class member variable in C++, you should really brush up your C++ basics, or programming with Qt is going to be stumbling in the dark.

Comment: @MikeP. It doesn't compile.

Comment: @hyde 

As I understand it to declare a class member variable I have to do something like adding it under a `private:`

Problem is, `uiactions.h` includes and is dependent on `mainwindow.h`, so when I try to do that in `mainwindow.h` I get `UiActions does not name a type` as an error.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink your architecture... Looking at your code, `MainWindow` uses `UIAction`. Therefore `MainWindow` should include `UIAction`, not the other way around. Also, your idea of member variables is a bit... misguided. Member variables often are (and should be) private yes, but that's only because it's a good idea in OOP, not because they *have* to be. So yes, study C++ (these comments are not a place for basic C++ tutoring).

Comment: @hyde I figured as much. I know member variables don't have to be private, I was just giving an example for where I would put the declaration. When I get a chance I'll go rework the architecture to make this work. Thanks for your help.